# A simple grammar lesson

Tags: wordplay

What is represented by the wordplay below?

> Pacific: Police
>   Indian: Hire
>   Mekong: Friend
>   Volga: Unthinkable
>   Ontario: Cutline
>   Baikal: Quite
>   Mediterranean: Bearing
>   Baltic: English

Comment: Left ones are related to water. That's how far I can go :(

Comment: @Techidiot That's a start :-D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's

> [I before E, except after C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C) (sea)

Because

> Of all the bodies of water on the left-hand side, those that are not Seas (not Lakes, Oceans, etc.) have the letter I before E in the right-hand word.